# How to restrict internet access

Tags: firefox, permissions

Can someone tell me if there is a way to limit Firefox internet access to specific websites pre-defined in a list. So the list will define the only allowed websites and not the blocked ones.

Answer (score 3):

There are several parental control apps that can do this, including [ProCon Latte](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1803/).  In the preferences, go to:

1. Main Filter tab
2. Select the Secure preset.
3. Whitelist tab
4. Select Enable whitelist
5. Enter the domains to whitelist.

These solutions aren't completely secure, so don't rely on them alone.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is better configured within a network. Proxies can work well with whitelists, as can DNS resolution services such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/). If you need a Firefox-specific solution, however, an add-on will do a better job.

Answer (score 1):

You can block certain sites by adding them to the hosts file with IP 127.0.0.0

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Internet_resources_blocking